# C# Select multiple values listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I've a Listbox but when I say :

```
 txtSelectedTables.Text += lbxTafels.GetItemText(lbxTafels.SelectedValue);
```

It only shows one thing in my textbox (even though I've selected multiple rows). So if I want to select multiple rows it doesn't put the values in txtSelectedTables.Text (it only shows one item).

So how can I select multiple rows and show it in a textbox.

Comment: [selecteditems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Like RadioSpace mentioned you probably want to look at the selectedItems property

Here is an example

```
foreach (var item in lbxTafels.SelectedItems)
{
     txtSelectedTables.Text += item.ToString();
}
```

Here is my full test function. If you are seeing a DataViewRow type name in the text box then maybe you have more going on than a ListBox and TextBox.

```
ListBox lbxTafels = new ListBox();
System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtSelectedTables = new TextBox();

//Add 2 items
lbxTafels.Items.Add("Hello");
lbxTafels.Items.Add("World");

//Select both items
lbxTafels.SetSelected(0,true);
lbxTafels.SetSelected(1, true);

//Set the textbox
foreach (var item in lbxTafels.SelectedItems)
{
    txtSelectedTables.Text += item.ToString();
}

Console.WriteLine(txtSelectedTables.Text);
```

The above function prints out

```
HelloWorld
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. Still saying "System.Data.DataRowViewSystem.Data.DataRowView"